# SonarQube 6.4 on Windows 10: Can't login

Tags: postgresql, sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

After fresh installation of SonarQube 6.4 on Windows 10 (using postgres database), i cannot log in into default admin/admin account. Tried to reset password (https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Authentication), also checked database and it seems it is not problem with connection (after analyzing project, table "projects" has been updated), but with password itself. Is it any way i can manually create new user with admin privileges or any other way to access admin panel? Maybe other way to reset password?

**EDIT:**

In web.log I've found error:

```
    2017.10.11 14:58:48 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.w.RootFilter] Processing of request /api/authentication/login failed
    javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter execution threw an exception
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.sonar.server.user.UserSessionFilter.doFilter(UserSessionFilter.java:87)
    at org.sonar.server.user.UserSessionFilter.doFilter(UserSessionFilter.java:71)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.SecurityServletFilter.doHttpFilter(SecurityServletFilter.java:72)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.SecurityServletFilter.doFilter(SecurityServletFilter.java:48)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.requestid.RequestIdFilter.doFilter(RequestIdFilter.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.RootFilter.doFilter(RootFilter.java:62)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at ch.qos.logback.access.tomcat.LogbackValve.invoke(LogbackValve.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.Base64Codec.encode(Base64Codec.java:21)
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.Base64UrlCodec.encode(Base64UrlCodec.java:22)
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtBuilder.base64UrlEncode(DefaultJwtBuilder.java:350)
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtBuilder.compact(DefaultJwtBuilder.java:296)
    at org.sonar.server.authentication.JwtSerializer.encode(JwtSerializer.java:98)
    at org.sonar.server.authentication.JwtHttpHandler.generateToken(JwtHttpHandler.java:84)
    at org.sonar.server.authentication.JwtHttpHandler.generateToken(JwtHttpHandler.java:96)
    at org.sonar.server.authentication.ws.LoginAction.doFilter(LoginAction.java:105)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter$GodFilterChain.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:126)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:95)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    ... 37 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting your instance to the right database? Also, anything interesting in any of the logs?

Comment: I have found error in web.log file. Edited my original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I highly suspect that you are using JDK 9.
For the time being SonarQube is not compatible with it.

You should switch to JDK 1.8.

Comment: After install JDK 8 and change PATH variable, everything works fine. Thanks!